# Broadcast by Notification Action not handled in BroadcastReceiver inside Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to build a notification while a music playback service is running and use the notification to interact with the service (play, pause, stop) using the Broadcast mechanism.

*(I know there is also the possibility to use PendingIntent.getService() as an action button in the notification, but I don't like this idea, because this would trigger the onStartCommand() of the service and I need to parse and analyze the Intent object to take action, which seems not as clean as the BroadcastReceiver approach, described below).*

Let's illustrate what we have so far with some (truncated) code.

1. We are **creating a Notification** object inside the service lifecycle, add an action button, and showing the notification using `startForeground()`.

   ```
   ...
   Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PlayerService.class);
   PendingIntent piStop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
   NotificationCompat.Action actionStopPlayback = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_stop_white_36dp, "Stop playback", piStop);
   notification.addAction(actionStopPlayback);
   ...
   ```
2. Then we are **registering a BroadcastReceiver inside the onCreate() of the service** (and unregistering it in onDestroy of course; this is a more simplified example).

   ```
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(getClass().toString(), "Broadcast received");
        }
   }, intentFilter);
   ```

And the final result is that the onReceive() of the receiver is never called. The service is a continuous one and is active when the Notification action sends the broadcast. Since I have no way of debugging broadcasts due to their nature, I'm kind of blocked here.

Comment: I used a mechanism in which Notification sends broadcast to a BroadcastReceiver 'A'. This BroadcastReceiver 'A' sends the broadcast to inner(inside service) BroadcastReceiver 'B'. In B's onReceive(), I handle the task. Here's a [sample github repo](https://github.com/rupinderjeet/NotificationActionButtonExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/rupinderjeet/notificationactionbuttonexample) I made for another answer. **See mike's answer**.

Answer (score 10):

You're creating this explicit `Intent` for the `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PlayerService.class);
```

This won't work for a couple of reasons. Explicit `Intent`s - those created for a specific target class - do not work with dynamically registered Receiver instances. Also, this is targeting the wrong class. A broadcast `Intent` with a `Service` class target will just fail outright. A `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent` would need a `BroadcastReceiver` class as the target.

With your current setup - the dynamically registered Receiver instance - you'll need to use an implicit `Intent`; i.e., an `Intent` with an action `String`, rather than a target class. For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.hasmobi.action.STOP_PLAYBACK");
```

You would then use that action `String` for the `IntentFilter` you're using to register the Receiver.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.hasmobi.action.STOP_PLAYBACK");
```

Do note that an `IntentFilter` can have multiple actions, so you can register a single Receiver to handle several different actions.

---

Alternatively, you could stick with using an explicit `Intent`, and statically register a `BroadcastReceiver` class in the manifest. For example:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
```

Then your `Intent` would be similar to:

```
Intent i = new Intent(PlayerService.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
```

However, this would require an additional step, as you would then need to somehow pass the broadcast info from `NotificationReceiver` to the `Service`; e.g., with an event bus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, etc.

Comment: Wow i've been trying to figure this out for hours that implicit intent is exactly what I was looking for Thank you!